# Javascript promise recursion return undefined

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

how do you return a recursive function when there's promise inside it,
here's my code so far

```js
loop = (i) => {
  new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(i)
      }, 100)
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res <= 5) {
        return loop(res + 1)
      } else {
        return true
      }
    })
}
console.log(loop(0))
```

Comment: `return new Promise(...)`? Otherwise each recursive call isn't part of the same chain.

Comment: You need to return the promise, and then you need to call `console.log()` when you resolve the promise.

Comment: @jonrsharpe can you please, explain it more to me. if I return this function as promise, where do i put the recursion then ?

Comment: A better question would be "what is this function supposed to do?" As an academic question the main exercise is to return something (you need a `return` keyword for arrow functions that have a block body rather than just a one liner) but as a _practical_ question, I'm not sure I understand why you'd ever use this. What's the real world use case?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans well sometimes you just meet a person as a good backend engineer, and sometimes not.

Comment: That doesn't really answer the question of why you would use this code: what is the real code supposed to do, that this is the simplified example code for? And if this is the actual code, what are you using it for?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 
that this is the simplified example code for ? that just a simplified example code so i can understand more about promise recursion.  what are you using it for ? I need to store a result of a test in mobile. I store the answer in an array of object like `result=[{A:A},...result]`,  user can review and edit before submit. somehow our table design only can store one answer each field. Hope you understand

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans this can easily be a retry mechanism where you try to do something (AJAX, DB operation, etc) that will be re-attempted if it fails, for example. Another option is to flatten recursion onto the event loop to prevent the stack blowing up. In the browser, you only have Promises as a way to access the microtask queue, so you'd need to do something like that, because macrotasks have a minimum wait time imposed on them and as such any recursive algorithm that will overflow the stack will be made dramatically slower if done as macrotasks.

Comment: That seems unlikely. If you have access to the scope that lets you define a promise return, involving a `setTimeout`, you have access to the scope that lets you define the variable that says whether a retry succeeded or not, which is the same scope in which you can define a counter so you can recurse _with that counter_ and cap your retries so you can move on to a failure path. Not to say you can't do this, because of course you _can_, just that you can do the same thing without promises.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans i think you missed something there, I use `setTimeout` just to mimic promise, actually i'm working with API there and it's of course return a promise. sorry if my explanation not so clear there. cheers~

Comment: ah, yes that does make a rather huge difference. If your code is not a true reflection of what you're doing, [point those things out please](/help/how-to-ask) so that there can be no confusion about what you're actually asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the promise. Then use `.then()` to wait for the promise to resolve, and call `console.log()` there.

```js
loop = (i) => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        resolve(i)
      }, 100)
    })
    .then((res) => {
      if (res <= 5) {
        return loop(res + 1)
      } else {
        return true
      }
    })
}
loop(0).then(result => console.log(result));
```